# Filtered lookup using SPServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, lookup-column, caml-query

I have 3 lists:
Schools,
Interactions,
Contacts

In the new form for a Interaction item I have a lookup field displaying a long list of contacts, however I need to filter this list to only display contacts associated with the particular school that the interaction is associated with.

Both the Contacts and the Interaction have a school_ID field and I basically need to filter the contacts lookup field to only display contacts 
WHERE contact.school_ID = Interactions.school_id (to use SQL lingo) 
however I'm not sure how to achieve that for a form.

I have found this method which looks relevant, but I'm not sure how exactly to customize it to compare school_ids
http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/207947

here's what I have come up with so far

```
$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdowns({
  relationshipWebURL: "",
  relationshipList: "Contacts",
  relationshipListChildColumn: "School_ID",
  relationshipListSortColumn: "",
  childColumn: "Interaction Contacts",
  CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name="school_id" /><Value Type="text">     
  [@school_id]</Value></Eq>",
  debug: true
});
```

Should I be using any encoding for white spaces in JavaScript-method parameters?

```
<FieldRef Name="school_id"
```

would retrieve the school_id from the item being looked up, ie. contact (correct?) but
How would I retrieve the school_id value from the Interaction item? which the Interaction item itself which the form is for.

Comment: [This](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns) lists all the parameters.

Comment: I've seen this, but unfortunatly still don't fully understand how to actually implement it for a lookup filter and not Cascading (got the cascading to work elsewhere)